# Creating an 'X' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am attempting to draw an 'X' using JavaScript.  I am having trouble starting the program and I'm having trouble trying to figure out what to type for each line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<font face="Courier New">
<body>
<h1>Work!</h1> 
<font face='Courier New'> 
<script> 
for (var row = 1; row < 5; row++) {
  for (var col = 0; col < max; col++) } {
    if (row===col || row + col===size-1) {
      document.write ('*')
    else
      document.write ('&Nbsp')
  }
</script> 
</font> 
</body> 
</html>
```

This is what I have so far.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have a few missing or misplaced curly braces and you didn't define `max`.

Comment: ...also didn't define `size`.

Comment: You're not "attempting to draw an 'X' using Notepad++". You're attempting to draw an 'X' using JS, using Notepad++ as your editor. Very first thing would be to get your braces balanced properly. The console will show you this and other errors; take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

funny exercise :), these two snippets are exactly the same

```js
var width = 10
var height = 10
var ratio = width/height; 

for (var row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < width; col++) {
        var diff = parseInt((row * ratio), 10);
        
        document.write (diff == col || col == width - diff - 1 ? '*' : '-')
            
        if(col == width - 1) {
            document.write ('<br>')
        }
    }
}
```

```js
var width = 20
var height = 20
var ratio = width/height; 

for (var row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < width; col++) {
        var diff = parseInt((row * ratio), 10);
        
        if (diff == col || col == width - diff - 1)
            document.write ('*')
        else
            document.write ('-')
            
        if(col == width - 1)
            document.write ('<br>')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer without the hyphens... :)

And by the way, in `document.write ('&Nbsp')` &Nbsp should be &nbsp for introducing space.

> **Non-breaking Space** 
>   A common character entity used in HTML is the non-breaking space: `&nbsp;`
>   A non-breaking space is a space that will not break into a new line.
>   Two words separated by a non-breaking space will stick together at the end of a line. This is handy when breaking the words might be disruptive.

Also an important note

> **Note:** Another common use of the non-breaking space is to prevent that browsers truncate spaces in HTML pages.If you write 10 spaces in
>    your text, the browser will remove 9 of them. To add real spaces to
>    your text, you can use the `&nbsp;` character entity.

```js
var width = 10
var height = 10
var ratio = width/height; 

for (var row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < width; col++) {
        var diff = Math.floor(row * ratio);
        
        document.write (diff == col || col == width - diff - 1 ? '*' :
 '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp') //Reduce/increse the number of &nbsp, inorder to get a wider or a narrower X
            
        if(col == width - 1) {
            document.write ('<br>')
        }
    }
}
```

Reference : [Non-breaking Space](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Comment: `parseInt((row * ratio), 10);` --- `parseInt` function expects the first argument to be a string. If all you need is to truncate a number then there is `Math.floor` for that.

Comment: And it should be `Math.floor(row * ratio)` then.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! It was exciting to see everything come in to place.